# Does the contraction "What's seems..." exist in English?

Tags: sentence-construction, contractions

> I was wondering what I could do about the problem I'm having with my big right toe.
>
> **What's seems to be the problem?**

If there is such a contraction, what is it? What *has* seems or what *is* seems? Or is it a typo?

Comment: It's like the author had two ideas & couldn't think which to go with... "What's the problem?" & "What seems to be the problem?"

Comment: @pyobum Actually, for an EFL learner, it's not clear that there is a typo. So, you can write a helpful, on-topic answer by explaining how a fluent speaker perceives it as a typo. Also, it might be helpful to explain why a beginner can easily misperceive a contraction in this context and why it's wrong. (I'm actually not convinced that it's a typographical error. It might be a transcription error.)

Comment: The source of your example would be helpful. Was it written or spoken? Locale/dialect might also be an issue. I think it is too hasty to judge it is a typo.

Comment: I don't think any dialects exist in which it's valid as written, so I vote typo.

Answer (score 4):

*What's* is the contraction form of *What is*. So to expand your phrase:

> **What is** seems to be the problem?

does not make sense and is not grammatical. You could say:

> What seems to be the problem?

or

> What does the problem seem to be?

If it was a spoken phrase, maybe it was misunderstood? Where the " 's " was actually the "s" in *seems*?

Comment: *What's* can also be *What has* or *What does*.